# How to Schedule Periodic Background Tasks in Android 13 and 14 Using WorkManager or Alternatives?

Tags: android, backgroundworker, android-workmanager, android-13

I'm currently developing an Android app, and I need to schedule periodic background tasks to run every hour on devices running Android 13 and 14. I've tried using the WorkManager with PeriodicWorkRequest, and it works perfectly on Android versions below 13. However, it doesn't seem to work as expected on Android 13 and 14.

I've checked the documentation and haven't found any specific issues related to these Android versions. Additionally, I've heard that some mobile manufacturers may not allow certain background tasks. Can anyone provide guidance on how to schedule periodic background tasks for each hour on Android 13 and 14 using WorkManager or any other suitable approach, considering potential restrictions by mobile manufacturers? Your insights and solutions would be greatly appreciated!

My Manifest Permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
```

My Notification Helper

```
object NotificationHandler {
    private const val CHANNEL_ID = "transactions_reminder_channel"

    fun createNotification(context: Context, title: String, content: String) {
        //  No back-stack when launched
        val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
            flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
        }
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context, 0, intent,
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
            else PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        )

        createNotificationChannel(
            context,
            title,
            content
        ) // This won't create a new channel everytime, safe to call

        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(content)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent) // For launching the MainActivity
            .setAutoCancel(true) // Remove notification when tapped
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)

        with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    context,
                    Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS
                ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                return
            }
            notify(1, builder.build())
        }
    }

    /**
     * Required on Android O+
     */
    private fun createNotificationChannel(context: Context, title: String, content: String) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            val channel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, title, importance).apply {
                description = content
            }
            val notificationManager: NotificationManager =
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }
    }
}
```

My Application Class

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class App : Application(), Configuration.Provider {
    @Inject
    lateinit var notificationWorkManagerFactory: NotificationWorkManagerFactory
    override fun getWorkManagerConfiguration(): Configuration {
        return Configuration.Builder()
            .setMinimumLoggingLevel(Log.DEBUG)
            .setWorkerFactory(notificationWorkManagerFactory)
            .build()
    }
}

class NotificationWorkManagerFactory @Inject constructor() : WorkerFactory() {
    override fun createWorker(
        appContext: Context,
        workerClassName: String,
        workerParameters: WorkerParameters
    ): ListenableWorker {
        return NotificationWorker(appContext, workerParameters)
    }
}
```

My Worker Class

```
class NotificationWorker @AssistedInject constructor(
    @Assisted var context: Context,
    @Assisted parameters: WorkerParameters,
) :
    CoroutineWorker(context, parameters) {
    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        return try {
            NotificationHandler.createNotification(context = context, title = "Hi from CoroutineWorker", "CoroutineWorker helps support multi-threaded coroutine usage in common code that works in Kotlin/Native and on JVM until kotlinx.")
            Result.success()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d("TAG", "doWork: "+e.message)
            Result.failure()
        }
    }
}
```

And, This is my Activity

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val context = LocalContext.current
            val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
            val workManagerState = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
            WorkerTheme {
                LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {
                    val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(this@MainActivity)
                    val request: PeriodicWorkRequest =
                        PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<NotificationWorker>(
                            30,
                            TimeUnit.MINUTES
                        ).build()
                    workManager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
                        "reminder_notification_work",
                        ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.UPDATE,
                        request
                    )
                    workManager.getWorkInfosForUniqueWorkLiveData("reminder_notification_work")
                        .observe(lifecycleOwner) { workInfo ->
                            workInfo.forEach {
                                workManagerState.value = it.state.toString()
                            }
                        }
                }
                Text(
                    text = "Hello ${workManagerState.value}!",
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When the phone boots start a ForegroundService and keep it running all the time. Then use AlaramManager to periodically run your task. It's not possible to start the ForegroundService when you want to run the task and then quit it. Because then you won't be allowed to start a ForegroundService if your app is closed (not visible to the user).

Comment: You might also want to take a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS) but I cannot tell how exactly it behaves.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of issues you have with android 13/14 and `PeriodicWorkRequest`. I am also using it with android 13/14 and does not have any issue. My usecase is updating the widgets every 15mins. So far i did not regognized a big issue.

The time of execution of the work could diff because the system is deciding when to execute the work even you configured every 60 mins. It could take a bit longer until executing. Huge benefit of the WorkManager and `PeriodicWorkRequest` that they also outlive a reboot.

Could you post code snipped how you configure it? Are you targeting newest compile/target SDK?

Comment: Hi @Dimi,

Yes, I've noticed that the time it takes to execute work can vary across different versions of Android. However, I'm experiencing an issue where my worker isn't starting on my Pixel 7a device.

And, I am using minSdk = 21 and targetSdk = 34 SDK's configuration.

Comment: Ok yes just checked snipped and it looks in general fine. Questions sounds stupid but did you check that Notification sending is working on that device? Maybe worker is doing his job but permission or some disturb setting on the pixel is set up. I would log and check.

Comment: OK, i have updated the code

Comment: Starting from android 13 you need runtime permissions for posting notifications. `Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS` are you requesting these in your app? Like `activity.requestPermissions(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS), 1)` if not then the WorkManager is probably working but posting of notifications just not working

Comment: Yes right it was already granted, I've granted the permission manually